# how do i handle value when the value is null or Empty using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

i have this code that returns all tickets with reply info so when there is no status value in Ticket_Reply entered i need to show "XXX"

```
enter    var query = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets
                     join pr in Db.Technical_problem on st.Technical_problem_Id equals pr.Technical_problem_Id
                     join x in 

                     from rp in Db.Ticket_Reply.GroupBy(m =>
       m.Support_Tecket_Id).Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).FirstOrDefault())
                     join tr in Db.trainers on rp.trainer_id equals tr.trainer_id
                     select new {rp,tr}


       on st.Support_Tecket_Id equals x.rp.Support_Tecket_Id into g

       from gx in g.DefaultIfEmpty()



                select new SupportTicketsDetails
            {

                Status = gx.rp.Status,



                }).ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.Created_Date);
```

thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming gx.rp.Status is a string Try using the ternary conditional operator e.g.

```
Status = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gx.rp.Status) ? "XXX":gx.rp.Status
```

i.e

```
enter    var query = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets
                 join pr in Db.Technical_problem on st.Technical_problem_Id equals pr.Technical_problem_Id
                 join x in 

                 from rp in Db.Ticket_Reply.GroupBy(m =>
   m.Support_Tecket_Id).Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).FirstOrDefault())
                 join tr in Db.trainers on rp.trainer_id equals tr.trainer_id
                 select new {rp,tr}


   on st.Support_Tecket_Id equals x.rp.Support_Tecket_Id into g

   from gx in g.DefaultIfEmpty()



            select new SupportTicketsDetails
        {

            Status = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gx.rp.Status) ? "XXX":gx.rp.Status,



            }).ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.Created_Date);
```